# Should I use @media print for a page that is solely used for printing?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Let's say I have a certain page with a print button. When I click on the button it will bring me to a separate page with the same information, but designed for printing. I considered using @media print on the same page, but there are too many modifications for this specific application, therefor I'm creating a whole new page for printing. My question is: In the styles for the print page, should I still use @media print in the CSS and have all my styles inside of that? Or can I just start writing my CSS rules as normal (ie. without the media query). Are there any drawbacks to not using the media query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, better off not to use. Drawbacks are for Browsers that have no or poor support for Media Queries. Only use Media Queries when the display CSS changes for the destination rendering.